# hMailServer SMTP error

Tags: smtp, hmailserver

I have hMailServer installed. I can send emails and everything is ok. I have only one problem. When i try to send an email to gmail.com i recive an "undelivered" email and this link: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336

Does anyone know what can i do to fix this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably have more of a problem than you realize; other mail destinations won't be so helpful and descriptive in explaining why (or even letting you know that) they are rejecting e-mail sent from your server.

You need to do as the message suggests: Get a legitimate relay to send the mail through. Depending on what you are sending the mail for, how much you are sending, etc; that might not be easy to do at all.

If it's just for your personal mail sending; just use your ISP's SMTP server.

Comment: Yes, it is my personal web server. How can i find my ISP SMTP server ?

Comment: Well for a start, have a look at your email program? Or their support pages should have details.

Comment: i thing is smtp.ips.tld. Now i recive this Remote server replied: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b17sm3164244bku.8

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing wrong with the hMailserver side of things but you need to ensure you have a proper SPF record in your DNS. What that Google message is telling you is that it failed to find your sending address in the SPF record, hence you have not declared it as authorized to send mail for your domain.